# Add last week of every year to the next week

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

How could I remove the last week of every year and add it to the next week in general code for all numeric columns?

```
df
  date      value
2019-12-20   0
2019-12-27   3
2020-01-03   7
...
2020-12-18   0
2020-12-25   4 
2021-01-01   7
```

Expected Output

```
  date      value
2019-12-20   0
2020-01-03   10
...
2020-12-18   0
2021-01-01   11
```

Comment: For transparency you could add a "financial year" column that you calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I've assumed your DataFrame contains only one row per week (it looks like you only have Fridays here). I've also assumed there is no missing week (i.e. no Friday is skipped) and they are time-sorted (if not, just call `df = df.sort_values("date")` first and you're good).

The following snippet should solve your issue (explanations are in the code):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [
        "2019-12-20", "2019-12-27",
        "2020-01-03", "2020-12-18",
        "2020-12-25", "2021-01-01"
    ],
    "value": [0, 3, 7, 0, 4, 7],
})

numeric_columns = ["value"]

# Compute whether a row is the last week of a year
year = df["date"].str[:4]
is_last_week = year != year.shift(-1).fillna(year.iloc[-1])
print(is_last_week)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: date, dtype: bool

# Take the value from those rows
values_on_last_week = df[numeric_columns].where(is_last_week)
print(values_on_last_week)

   value
0    NaN
1    3.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    NaN

# Shift values one row down
shifted_values_on_last_week = values_on_last_week.shift()
print(shifted_values_on_last_week)

   value
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    4.0

# Put zeroes instead of NaNs
shifted_values_on_last_week = shifted_values_on_last_week.fillna(0)
print(shifted_values_on_last_week)

   value
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    3.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    4.0

# Add this to df
df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns] + shifted_values_on_last_week
print(df)

         date  value
0  2019-12-20    0.0
1  2019-12-27    3.0
2  2020-01-03   10.0
3  2020-12-18    0.0
4  2020-12-25    4.0
5  2021-01-01   11.0

# Drop the rows we don't want anymore
df = df[~is_last_week]
print(df)

         date  value
0  2019-12-20    0.0
2  2020-01-03   10.0
3  2020-12-18    0.0
5  2021-01-01   11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to is look at min and max dates for each year in the dataset.

```
data = '''  date      value
2019-12-20   0
2019-12-27   3
2020-01-03   7
2020-12-18   0
2020-12-25   4
2021-01-01   7'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#get the max dates rows and min dates rows
dfmax = df[df['date'].dt.month==12].groupby(df['date'].dt.year).max().reset_index(drop=True)
dfmin = df[df['date'].dt.month==1].groupby(df['date'].dt.year).min().reset_index(drop=True)


# add the values
dfh = dfmin
dfh['value'] = dfmax['value'] +  dfmin['value']

# remove unwanted rows from initial df
dfidx = dfh['date'].tolist()
df = df[~df['date'].isin(dfidx)].copy()
dfidx = dfmax['date'].tolist()
df = df[~df['date'].isin(dfidx)].copy()

# piece it back together with recalculated dates
dfnew = pd.concat([dfmin, df]).sort_values('date')
dfnew
```

Output

```
        date  value
0 2019-12-20      0
0 2020-01-03     10
3 2020-12-18      0
1 2021-01-01     11
```